# While Loop when checking if record exists - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random, mysqli, while-loop

I need to generate a random number. After I generate the number, I need to check my table to see if that number has been generated before. If the random number is not unique, I'll re-regenerate the number until a unique number is generated.

Here is my code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database);

$random = rand(1000, 9999);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE randomnumber = '.$random .'");

$num_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows ($result);

while ($num_rows > 0) {

$random = rand(1000, 9999);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 }

$random = rand(1000, 9999);
```

I need to know if this algorithm is correct - esp. the while loop. Or is there another more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason for you doing this? You can get a unique identifier for a given row by using a primary key.

Comment: Have you considered what will happen when you get more than 8999 entries (and as you approach that value, the while-loop will run for a longer and longer time)? If you need a value to confirm an email address, you don't have to have a unique value as the code (just as the identifier) - and it should have more than 8999 possible values.

Comment: How do I generate a unique 4 digit key using a primary key? Is it via PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: as a side note you should check out  `mt_rand()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

Comment: @CodyRaspien - a primary key is generally going to be a unique number already.

Comment: @andrewsi Really? That's a sweeping generalisation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better if you list enabled randomnumber in the selected day, for example you generate random loop each date of script executed

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database);
$randomnumbers = [];
$query = "SELECT randomnumber FROM tablex WHERE (DATE(tablex.randomdate) = DATE(NOW()))";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $randomnumbers[] = $row['randomnumber'];
}
do {
 $random = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
} while (in_array($random, $randomnumbers));
```

Answer (score 2):

I cleaned up your code, that fixes most problems (but beware that after 8999 calls, it will still loop infinitely).

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database);
do {
$random = mt_rand(1000,9999);
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE email = '.$random .'");
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
} while ($num_rows > 0);
```

Comment: @CodyRaspien How long (and what charset) can your token be? And what is the purpose of it?

Comment: If I move $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE email = '.$random .'");
into the loop, will that break the loop if the number is found?

Comment: 4 digit long. It's for a couponing system.

Comment: 1. Yes it will. But you need to put it at the right spot. 2. Because afterwards your while-loop will be an infinite loop (it won't find any free numbers anymore and just keep generating and testing them infinitely and thereby consume all your CPU and Database resources)

Comment: @Aragorn0 The updated answer will be expensive to run though. What is the best way to generate a random number but then check if it exists - if it does, re-generate, else, use the random number?

Comment: @CodyRaspien It isn't more expensive to run than your old version. It is just written in a more compact form. If you want it faster, I'd suggest you using a file or Redis to store the numbers. You can't really make it faster other than speeding up the checks.